# Keyframes image slide works but not on WordPress

Tags: html, css, wordpress, slide

I'm using keyframes to have an image slide. I've already done this on another site, and I'm using the same CSS. It also works on JS Fiddle, but it doesn't work on WordPress. I tried getting rid of the default classes WordPress put on the images, and I even tried using !important.
Code on JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Ldej2wvd/

```
    .sideImage {
    width: 300px;
    height: 180px;
    }
    .slideshow {
        position: relative;
        height: 220px;

    }
    .slideshow figure {
        position: absolute;
        opacity: 1;
        margin-left: -20px;
        width: 300px;
        height: 220px;
        overflow: hidden; 
    }
    .slideshow figure:nth-child(2) {
        animation: xfade 36s 0s infinite;
       -moz-animation: xfade 36s 0s infinite;
       -webkit-animation: xfade 36s 0s infinite;
       -o-animation: xfade 36s 0s infinite;
    }
    .slideshow figure:nth-child(3) {
        animation: xfade 36s 6s infinite;
       -moz-animation: xfade 36s 6s infinite;
       -webkit-animation: xfade 36s 6s infinite;
       -o-animation: xfade 36s 6s infinite;
    }
    .slideshow figure:nth-child(4) {
       animation: xfade 36s 12s infinite;
       -moz-animation: xfade 36s 12s infinite;
       -webkit-animation: xfade 36s 12s infinite;
       -o-animation: xfade 36s 12s infinite;
    }
    .slideshow figure:nth-child(5) {
       animation: xfade 36s 18s infinite;
       -moz-animation: xfade 36s 18s infinite;
       -webkit-animation: xfade 36s 18s infinite;
       -o-animation: xfade 36s 18s infinite;
    }
    .slideshow figure:nth-child(6) {
       animation: xfade 36s 24s infinite;
       -moz-animation: xfade 36s 24s infinite;
       -webkit-animation: xfade 36s 24s infinite;
       -o-animation: xfade 36s 24s infinite;
    }
    .slideshow figure:nth-child(7) {
       animation: xfade 36s 30s infinite;
       -moz-animation: xfade 36s 30s infinite;
       -webkit-animation: xfade 36s 30s infinite;
       -o-animation: xfade 36s 30s infinite;
    }



    <table><tr><td width="400px">
    <div id="KekoaTextBox" color="#161447"><h3><strong>This site is a resource for the language industry, including translation, interpretation, and localization. Also, check here and our <a href="https://www.facebook.com/groups/689448181135760/">Facebook page</a> to stay up to date on club events. Club meetings are Thursdays at 11 AM!</strong></h3></div>
    </div></td><td width="300px"><div class="slideshow">
    <figure><img src="http://l10n.byu.edu/files/2015/03/IMG_0020-225x300.jpg" alt="Trados Dylan" class=" sideImage" /></figure>
    <figure><img src="http://l10n.byu.edu/files/2014/11/Screen-Shot-2015-02-04-at-2.44.27-PM-300x223.png" alt="Benjamin Dowdy" width="300" height="223" class=" sideImage" /></figure><figure><img src="http://l10n.byu.edu/files/2015/02/IMG_20150212_112128_4651-300x225.jpg" alt="IMG_20150212_112128_465[1]" class=" sideImage" /></figure><figure><img src="http://l10n.byu.edu/files/2015/01/ClubFlier-300x225.jpg" alt="Opening Flier" width="300" height="225" class=" sideImage" /></figure><figure><img src="http://l10n.byu.edu/files/2014/12/BYU_campus_dark_winter-300x128.jpg" alt="BYU campus at night" width="300" height="128" class=" sideImage" /></figure><img src="http://l10n.byu.edu/files/2015/02/IMG_20150212_112215_0601-300x169.jpg" alt="Trados training" class=" sideImage" /></figure></div></td></tr>
    <tr><td>[widgets_on_pages]</td>
    </tr></table>
```

Comment: I can't see why the same piece of HTML and CSS would work on JSFiddle or locally and not when printed by Wordpress.

Please do the following:

+ Test every variation on the same browser
+ Test every variation on the same OS
+ Make sure there is no change in class name from one environment to the other
+ Make sure the CSS is actually being called/printed on the source code

If exactly every condition is the same in every instance, there should be no difference in behavior. That's why I think there must be a difference in the actual code that is being read by the browser.

Do I make sense?

Comment: Do you have a good understanding of how to use the browser's code inspector? It will help you identify these issues

Comment: Looking at the source I realized that WordPress was adding silly <p> and </p> tags in the CSS anywhere where I had extra lines. After getting rid of extra lines it worked just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the source I realized that WordPress was adding silly <p> and </p> tags in the CSS anywhere where I had extra lines (blank lines). After getting rid of extra lines it worked just fine.

Comment: I guess the code inspection helped seeing inconsistent markup between environments